# .NET Compact Framework: combine two images in one / overlay one image on another

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have two png's and I'd like to draw one on top of the other. Is there a good way of doing this in .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

The first image is the background, the second image is an overlay. The overlay will have transparency.

My goal would be for the overlay to be "added" to the base image. Think four star rating image added over a CD cover image.

Comment: Does one have transparency?  What, exactly, do you mean by "combine"?  What do you want to do with overlapping colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the mechanism I used on [this project](http://resistance.codeplex.com).  It's exactly the same as what you're after.